# Pull just the content of a repo into a folder?

Tags: git

I'm working with Git programmatically. I have two repos, A and B. I want to clone A into a dir "./foo", then get just the contents of repo B into "./foo". So ./foo will be linked to repo A, but have all the files from both.

Is there any efficient way to do this? Right now, my pattern looks like this:

```
clone repoA into ./foo
clone repoB into a temp directory
delete .git from temp directory
copy contents of temp directory into ./foo
```

This works, but is a little slower than i'd like. Any better way?

Comment: Would submodules work here?

Comment: The contents of a repo are *commits* (which are the history of the repository). The description you give is about *files*, i.e., *one* commit; so that's not really getting the contents of B into A. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re only interested in the file contents of Repo B, I would suggest that when you’re cloning it, you use the `--depth` option to copy only the most recent commit:

```
git clone --depth 1 repoB.url /path/to/tmp/dir
```

This creates a *shallow* clone of the repository and not having to download all the other commits will greatly speed up the cloning.

Comment: Wow! Fastest acceptance ever! Are you sure you don't want to wait and see if someone comes up with something better?